# Codeigniter 3 - how to callback to home

Tags: php, codeigniter

if i´m on a category/index/$1 Site of my Page and want to call back to domain.com/home, it doesn't work for me.

Thats my routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['admin'] = 'admin/login';
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'category/index/$1';
$route['category/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'category/index/$1/$2';
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

If i call domain.com/about and click on my navigation "home", its working. but if i make domain.com/aboutdetails/index/1 he make on home click this one:

domain.com/aboutdetails/index/home

htaccess

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|style|cdn|check\.php)

RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Reorder places of `$route['category/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'category/index/$1/$2';` and `$route['category/(:any)'] = 'category/index/$1';`.

Comment: can you so us about your controller and view?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thats was my first idea too. But if a creat over my dashboard now a external link > he make domain.com/domainextern.com/ So i cant use this

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: i creat the navigation links over my admin dashboard with 
        <li><a <?php echo $item->position ?> href="<?php echo $item->navilink ?>"><?php echo $item->title ?></a></li> And if i put your code befor, i cant get creat extern links.

Answer (score 0):

If you want go to home with your configuration router using domain.com.
If you want use domain.com/home you add next line route:

```
$route['home'] = 'home/index';
```

Considerer use initial en and limiter( regex ), example:

```
$route['^home$'] = 'home/index';
```

Good, To print link don't use base_url(), it is use to load assets or other an return project root, Use site_url().

In the application/config.php set empty to $config['index_page']:

```
//$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And then create link with site_url():

```
site_url( 'home' );
```

If you want create link with more params you maybe pass array.

```
site_url( array( 'home', $param2 ) );
```